# Comparing BigDecimal

Tags: java

I have following two BigDecimal objects.

```
    BigDecimal one = new BigDecimal(3.0);
    BigDecimal two = new BigDecimal(3.00);

    System.out.println(one.scale());//0
    System.out.println(two.scale());//0
    System.out.println(one.equals(two));//true
```

I've read JavaDocs, but anywhere can't understand what is difference between `equals` and `compareTo` method. JavaDoc says that these objects isn't equal by `equals` method and result must be `false`, but result is `true`. I'm confused.

Comment: Change `new BigDecimal(3.0);` to `new BigDecimal("3.0");` and you will see the difference.

Comment: Your parameters are the same no matter how many zeros you add,  `3.0 == 3.00` is `true` .

Comment: https://github.com/mortezaadi/bigdecimal-utils

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the `String` constructor to get the correct scales, because the [`BigDecimal(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29) will get the small scale possible

> translates a double into a BigDecimal which is the exact decimal representation of the double's binary floating-point value. **The scale of the returned BigDecimal is the smallest value such that (10scale × val) is an integer.**

More precision about the documentations :

## [BigDecimal.equals(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Compares this BigDecimal with the specified Object for equality. **Unlike compareTo, this method considers two BigDecimal objects equal only if they are equal in value and scal**e (thus 2.0 is not equal to 2.00 when compared by this method).

## [BigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigDecimal%29)

> Compares this BigDecimal with the specified BigDecimal. **Two BigDecimal objects that are equal in value but have a different scale (like 2.0 and 2.00) are considered equal by this method**. This method is provided in preference to individual methods for each of the six boolean comparison operators (<, ==, >, >=, !=, <=). The suggested idiom for performing these comparisons is: (x.compareTo(y)  0), where  is one of the six comparison operators.

You will find that the `equals` use the scale for the comparison, giving some "strange" result.

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal("2"); //scale 0
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal("2.00"); //scale 2

bd1.equals(bd2); //false
bd1.compareTo(bd2); //0 => which means equivalent
```

Comment: I don't think its useful to cite the JavaDoc since the OP just made a "little" mistake in his test-case. And already noted that he has read it already.

Comment: @devpuh "_but anywhere can't understand what is difference between equals and compareTo method_", means it was not understood... It will be more complete for future readers. So yes, it is useful since OP didn't mention what he was trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use compareTo for BigDecimal. This method will return a number greater than zero if a > b, 0 if a == b, and less than zero if a < b

Answer (score 3):

Change new `BigDecimal(3.0);` to new `BigDecimal("3.0");` and you will see the difference.

You used the constructor [`new BigDecimal(double val)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-) with a double-literal which value is just `3` it doesn't matter if you write `3.0` or `3.0000`.
Also be careful with this constructor since it represents the *exact decimal representation of the double's binary floating-point value*, therefor `new BigDecimal(0.1)` creates a BigDecimal with the value `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` (See JavaDoc)

Better (always) use the constructor [`new BigDecimal(String val)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Nice point, please have a look at [this post](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/NUM10-J.+Do+not+construct+BigDecimal+objects+from+floating-point+literals).